# Terminal hang after entering login SSH password on server. Did I just got hacked?

Tags: ssh

I was doing routine maintenance on my server. As usual, after connecting successfully to my server on port 22, I was shown a login prompt:

```
$ ssh admin@1.2.3.4
admin@1.2.3.4's password:
```

Seeing no warning whatsover, I entered my password. Then my terminal hanged and the black rectangular cursor key stopped flashing. The desktop is still functioning as normal. I tried <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to cancel previous action. It didn't respond. I quickly close the terminal.

Did I just got hacked? How do I know if this is a software glitch or security issue? Not knowing whether I have successfully logged in, what would you do in my situation?

Answer (score 4):

A hang after entering your password usually means either that the connection dropped or that the server crashed; occasionally it means the server is in a low-memory situation and needs to swap in (or load) the shell before it can display it to you.  I wouldn't worry about it from a security perspective.

If someone had hacked things so that you were being redirected to another server, OpenSSH (I assume that's what you're using) would have detected a key mismatch, thrown up an error message, and flatly prohibited you from entering your password or otherwise proceeding with the connection:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
...
Host key verification failed.
```

The message is not even remotely subtle.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the DNS settings of the server to which you are connecting, particularly whether it can resolve its own hostname to the correct IP address. I don't know why this would happen, but I have seen very slow SSH logins when the remote host can't resolve its own hostname.

Answer (score 0):

In case the SSH login hangs after entering password

then my issue was "Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded: The maximum number of active connections for UID 0 has been reached (g-dbus-error-quark, 8)"

Solution is to restart 'systemd-logind' service and release those
In case it failed then need to restart the server/computer.